# How do I run udhcpc manually to request it to renew DHCP lease?

Tags: dhcp, busybox

I'm using udhcpc which is a part of Busybox v1.24.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.
I have to renew DHCP lease without releasing current IP and without requesting new IP.
In other words I want udhcpc to send DHCPREQUEST instead of DHCPDISCOVER.
There is no "renew" parameter the only option is to send USR1 signal to udhcpc that is already running in background do that.
But I'm wondering if I can run udhcpc with some option to renew existing lease?

Answer (score 1):

Sending the `USR1` signal seems to be the documented method to renew a DHCP lease. According to the [code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/busybox/0.60.4/source/networking/udhcpc.c), this signal explicitly jumps past *discover* and right to *request*.

Otherwise, it seems that simply running `udhcpc` causes the lease to be renewed too, but there does not appear to be any provision in the code to skip the *discover* state.

I would suggest that the signal be your first port of call, and if that doesn't suit your needs, then consider running a new instance of `udhcpc` and then immediately sending it the `USR1` signal.